# Postgresql trigger: check total number of rows in WHEN conditon

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table which needs a trigger to maintain the total number of rows to be 100. The trigger works in the way that once there is a new row inserted into table, the oldest row will be deleted. Obviously, I need to check if the total number of rows already reach to 100 before the trigger start to work.

I considered to use `WHEN (condition)` for the trigger, and here the condition can be a subquery `(SELECT count(*) FROM mytablename)>100`. But problem is currently the WHEN condition does not support subqueries.

Unfortunately, I failed to find another way to count the rows in a table without writing query.

Any idea how to handle this? Is there any other way to config the trigger? Or am I supposed to check that threshold outside the trigger?

Comment: I'd quite like to see *why* you want to do this. What's the goal of restricting the table to 100 rows? How strict do you have to be? Do you care if you get 104 rows?

Comment: @CraigRinger Good point! I don't care if I get 104 rows! It's fine to have not strictly 100 rows, but should be larger than that and won't exceed a lot. And If you ask me why I want to do that, I have to say it's just needed to be like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with a trigger `WHEN` condition, nor would it make sense to do so if you could. If there are two concurrent inserts, your trigger condition would run the `WHEN` condition twice, both would see that there are 99 rows in the table, and **both would permit the next row to be inserted without a corresponding delete**.

Since PostgreSQL doesn't support SQL assertions (does anything?) your best bet is a trigger that always runs on every insert. This trigger:

- LOCKs the table `IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`
- `COUNT`s rows
- `DELETE`s the oldest row if appropriate

... however, there's a wrinkle. The `LOCK`, while necessary, is what's called a "lock upgrade". The transaction will always have a lock on the table already, but it'll be a weaker lock. This is a near-guaranteed way to create deadlocks between concurrent transactions in a concurrent environment because two or more transactions have a weaker lock, and they each want a stronger lock that is blocked by each others' weak locks on the table.

The only real way around that is to either use only one transaction at a time with this table, or always have transactions that use the table `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before doing anything with it. Both require the client application to be aware of what is going on.

In general I don't think aiming for a strictly fixed row-count in SQL tables is a great idea. You haven't explained *why* you want this, so it's hard for me to make suggestions about alternatives, but one possibility might be to make the client app tolerant of small increases above the row-count limit, and do lazy cleanup:

- When there's an insert into the table, send a `NOTIFY`
- Have a `LISTEN`ing program wake up when it sees the `NOTIFY`, grab a whole-table `EXCLUSIVE MODE` lock that blocks insert/update/delete but permits select, and then delete excess rows.

The handy thing about this is that `NOTIFY` is only sent when a transaction commits. So you won't have the same kind of locking issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I don't need strict 100 rows, some number above that a little bit is fine. Actually, I'm just looking for a way to minimize the table size while keeping enough records, for example, 100 newest records. Does this make sense?

Comment: @HaoHuang Yes, that makes sense, and for that I *strongly* recommend just having a periodic job (cron job etc) go through and purge old records. Doing it with triggers will probably be painful.

Answer (score 1):

Such conditions on other rows cannot be tested reliably in a trigger as [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20917007/238814) explains.

However, I believe a simple approach is possible, with the help of a sequence and an additional column in the table.

Initialization:

- create a sequence starting at 1 and cycling at 100.
- add an `int` or `smallint` column `RN` for the row number

Insertion logic (a kind of merge, actually):

- ask for the sequence's nextval (`SN`)
- update the row (each column gets the value of the new row) which matches `RN=SN` if it exists. Think of it as "recycling" the row.
- if the update didn't affect any row, then insert it as a new row, with `RN` taking `SN` as the value.

`RN` is expected to be always unique and between 1 and 100.
When several transactions insert concurrently, they'll target different `RN` so they won't lock each other. Locking may occur if more than 100 transactions are doing this concurrently, though.

Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE cycle_seq maxvalue 100 cycle;
CREATE TABLE tst(val1 int, val2 int, RN int);

CREATE FUNCTION cycling_insert(_val1 int, _val2 int) returns void AS
$$
declare
  _rn int:=nextval('cycle_seq');
begin
   UPDATE tst SET val1=_val1,val2=_val2 WHERE RN=_rn;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
     INSERT INTO tst VALUES(_val1,_val2,_rn);
   END IF;
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Nice idea, I also thought about using this kind of approach but haven't got a complete solution. From discussion above with other guys, I found my design requirement is much looser, so I've chosen the periodic cron approach described in other's answer. I may use your approach somewhere else in my design, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

No need for a when condition, if I get your question and requirement right. You could delete the excess rows directly, if you've an appropriate sort criteria to select those that are too old, e.g.:

```
create function trim_tbl() returns trigger as $$
begin
  delete from tbl
  where id in (select id from tbl order by id desc offset 100);
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger trim_tbl after insert on tbl
for each row execute procedure trim_tbl();
```

It could probably be a statement-level trigger, too.

That being said:

1. As @CraigRinger suggested in the comments after his answer, you'll get better performance with a periodic cron if your interest is merely to keep your table size small.
2. Your having only 100 rows in there essentialy guarantees a filtered seq  scan plan anytime you access it because of the low cardinality, so don't get confused by this when running explain analyze.

Comment: Where condition instead of When condition, interesting. I already chosen to do periodic cron, but your answer is pretty helpful, maybe I can adopt it somewhere else in my design. Thank you so much!